# Filtering xml nodes comparing two lists of nodes

Tags: xslt, filtering

I have two node lists which look like this:

First list:

```
<WebAddresses>
  <item>
   <AddressID>01</AddressID>
   <Street>Street01</Street>
   <State>Idaho<State>
   <Country>US</Country>
  <item>
  <item>
   <AddressID>02</AddressID>
   <Street>Street02</Street>
   <State>Kentucky<State>
   <Country>US</Country>
  <item>
</WebAddresses>
```

Second List

```
<Addresses>
  <row>
    <WebID>02</WebID>
    <Line1>Line1</Line1>
    <Line2>Line1</Line2>
    <State>Lousiana</State>
    <Country>US</Country>
  </row>
  <row>
    <WebID>03</WebID>
    <Line1>Line1</Line1>
    <Line2>Line2</Line2>
    <State>California</State>
    <Country>US</Country>
  </row>
</Addresses>
```

In my xslt I have

```
<xsl:variable name="webAddr" select="$webXML\\WebAddresses"/>
<xsl:variable name="appAddr" select="$AppXML\\Addresses"/>
```

I want to filter second list, eliminating those rows having `WebID` in first list items, So that output list has only the row with `WebID=03`. I tried the following:

```
 <xsl:variable name="leftX" select="$appAddr[not(WebID=$webAddr/AddressID)]"/>
```

But it is not filtering the data, but returning the unchanged `appAddr` list. I can do it through .net code, but was looking for an xslt way. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a few things for this to work.

**First, the `webAddr` and `appAddr` variables contain invalid XPaths. Change these to:**

```
<xsl:variable name="webAddr" select="$webXML//WebAddresses"/>
<xsl:variable name="appAddr" select="$AppXML//Addresses"/>
```

(or, better yet, if you know the exact XPaths needed, try to avoid the sometimes-wasteful `//` axis).

**Second, change your `leftX` variable to look like:**

```
<xsl:variable name="leftX" select="$appAddr/row[WebID = $webAddr/item/AddressID)]"/>
```

This template removes all `<row>` elements whose `<WebID>` child have a value equal to any of the `<AddressID>` grandchildren of `<WebAddresses>`.